# How to code show highest and lowest bar of mondays?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

How to code show highest and lowest bar of mondays(UTC 04.00 monday to tuesday ) indicator in pinescript , is that possible ?

I've created high and low levels of day but I've couldn't‏‏‎‏‏‏ set for monday especially. Can someone solve this problem ?‏‎‏‏‎

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dayofweek` built-in variable to figure out if it is Monday and update your variables accordingly.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

is_monday = (dayofweek == dayofweek.monday)
is_new_monday = (not is_monday[1] and is_monday)

bgcolor(is_new_monday ? color.new(color.blue, 85) : na)

var float high_price = high
var float low_price = low

if (is_new_monday)
    high_price := high
    low_price := low
else if (is_monday)
    if (high > high_price)
        high_price := high

    if (low < low_price)
        low_price := low

plot(high_price, "Monday High", color.green, 1, plot.style_circles)
plot(low_price, "Monday Low", color.red, 1, plot.style_circles)
```

[image]